# An example of a function $g:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ that is rotationally symmetric and "grows like $e^{\sigma t}$ in every direction".

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, entire-functions

Fix $\sigma >0$. I'm looking for a function $g:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ that can be the modulus of an analytic function (so $g=|q|$ for some analytic $q$) and grows like the exponential function $e^{\sigma t}$ "in every radial direction". More precisely, I want $g$ to have the property that for any $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$,

$$\sigma=\inf\left\{\rho:g(r,\theta)=O(e^{\rho r})\text{ as }r\to\infty\right\}$$

where the argument of $g$ is in polar coordinates. Is there a "canonical" or "simplest" $g$ with this property?

**Context**:

Suppose $f$ is an entire function that is not a polynomial. We say that $f$ is of *exponential type* $\sigma\in[0,\infty]$ if

$$\sigma=\inf\left\{A>0:|f(z)|=O\left(e^{A|z|}\right)\text{ as }|z|\to\infty\right\}$$

Suppose the type of $f$ is $\sigma\in[0,\infty)$. I want to see if there's a decomposition of $f$ that writes it as a product of two entire functions, one of type $\sigma$ and the other of type $0$. My first idea was to write $f(z)=e^{\sigma z}h(z)$ and try to prove that $h(z)$ has type $0$, but it occurred to me that $e^{\sigma z}$ "grows at a $\sigma$ rate" only as $\Re (z)\to\infty$, so this won't work. This thinking leads to the explicit counterexample $f(z)=e^{-\sigma z}$, which would necessitate $h(z)$ to be $e^{-2\sigma z}$ and hence not have type $0$.

Thus, it seems like a decomposition $f(z)=q(z)\cdot r(z)$ ($q$ has type $\sigma$ and $r$ had type $0$) must have the property that $q$ "grows with a $\sigma$ rate" *in every direction on the complex plane*. Taking norms and writing $z=x+yi$ yields $|f(x+yi)|=|q(x+yi)|\cdot|r(x+yi)|$, so it seems like we need

$$g(x,y):=|q(x+yi)|$$

to grow like $e^{\sigma t}$ in a radially symmetric fashion. My original question was an attempt to work backwards, that is, find a $g$ with the desired property and use $g(x,y)=|q(x+yi)|$ to try and figure out a closed-form for $q$.

Comment: Doesn't $f(x,y) = e^{\sigma\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ fill your need? If not, please add to the post whatever additional properties you need $f$ to have.

Comment: @GregMartin I deleted my previous comment because I really need $g$ to be however regular it needs to be to be modulus of some analytic function $q$.

Comment: Hint: in view of the polar Cauchy-Riemann equation $q_\theta=irq_r$,$$0=gg_\theta=\Re(q^\ast q_\theta)=-r\Im(q^\ast q_r)=(\tfrac{q^\ast}{q})_r\tfrac{q^2r}{2i},$$i.e. $q$ has $r$-independent phase for nonzero solutions. Now try the Ansatz $q=e^{a(r)+ib(\theta)}$ for real-valued functions $a,\,b$.

Comment: You can check $f(x,y)=Ce^{{\sigma \sqrt{x^+my^2}}^P}$ , which is a little more general than what @GregMartin gave. Not sure what you mean by Symmetry here , though that might make $m=1$. Not sure what mean my $O()$ here , though that might make $P=1$. I think , you can easily make this into a limit format , which might be easier to visualize & Solve.

Answer (score 0):

How about $$g(z) = |e^{\rho_1 z}+e^{-\rho_2 z}+e^{i \rho_3 z}+e^{-i \rho_4 z}|$$,
$\rho_i >0$ is a positive constant.

Also Check Hadamard factorization theorem.
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_factorization_theorem#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20and%20particularly%20in,is%20named%20for%20Jacques%20Hadamard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_factorization_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20and%20particularly%20in,is%20named%20for%20Jacques%20Hadamard).